# Skew symmetric matrices even size commutativity

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, matrices, matrix-equations

**Given Data in the question**

1. $w(t)=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
   0 &r(t)  &-q(t)  &p(t) \\ 
    -r(t)& 0 &p(t)  &q(t) \\ 
    q(t)& -p(t) &0  & r(t)\\ 
    -p(t)&-q(t)  &-r(t)  &0 
   \end{bmatrix}\tag1$
2. $B(t)= -\int_{0}^{t} w(t) \ dt \tag 2 $

**Question**

**1.  Can we clearly prove $B(t)w(t)=w(t)B(t)$. Means can we prove the commutative  property between these two? 
   2. What is    $ \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}{e^{B(t)}} $?**

NB :: Remember this question is different from skew symmetric matrices of size 3. Because skew symmetric matrices of odd size has zero determinant. Here it is even size